# How to get the exact lat lng from Google Map url

Tags: javascript, regex, google-maps, url, substring

> This is an example of google map url:
> https://www.google.com.kh/maps/place/Photo+Cafe/@11.5209012,104.943248,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x310957360e265763:0x4a3989b09e7ae9c7!8m2!3d11.520896!4d104.945442?hl=en

I have searched around about google map regex and found this post: http://www.regexpal.com/93657

In the link above, its working but the lat lng that i get from the url is not a right one.

> /@11.5209012,104.943248,17z

I think it came from the center of the map because when i moved the map the url also changed. But for the data params:

> /data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x310957360e265763:0x4a3989b09e7ae9c7!8m2!3d11.520896!4d104.945442?hl=en
>
> 11.520896, 104.945442

i have copied the numbers in the data params and it was the exact position that i want.

so how can i get this number 11.520896, 104.945442 from the sample google map url by regex or is there a better way to get the right position of the map?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Whoops, gotta use capture groups with js...  [Pattern Demo/Breakdown](https://regex101.com/r/j60by9/9)

```js
var regEx = /![34]d(-?[\d\.]+)/g;
var data  = "/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x310957360e265763:0x4a3989b09e7ae9c7!8m2!3d11.520896!4d104.945442?hl=en";
var match = regEx.exec(data);

while(match !== null) {
    console.log(match[1]);
    match = regEx.exec(data);
}
```

Comment: its working now, thank my friend :) you saved my day.